# format inputstream field to json string on java

Tags: java, json

I have a problem when convert a entity to json string in java.
I have a inputstream field on Customer entity and I want convert Customer entity to json string. All fields of Customer is convert OK, however the value of inputstream field is null after converted.

My code:

```
protected String convertSettingText(Customer customer) {
    JsonViewJson json = new JsonViewJson();
    String customerJson = json.format(customer);
    return customerJson;
}
```

How to convert this field (inputstream field) of Customer to json and parse this json to Customer entity?

Comment: which json parser are you using

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Jackson`, then you can convert the object to a string like this :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
...

protected String convertSettingText(Customer customer) {
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(customer);
}
```

You can also use Google's `Gson` like below :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
return gson.toJson(customer);
```

To ignore null values, you can either set the mapper to exclude null values like this :

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Or you can add this annotation at the top of your class like this:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Customer
{
  String inputstream;
}
```